# Trying to remove padding from my h2 titles

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

Hi I'm trying to bring my h2 Titles towards the top of the div they're in, but I can't figure out how to remove the padding / margin / whatever it is that is causing them to be spaced down so far.

This is the first time I've tried using "sections" and I'm using them to create a parallax scrolling website.  I've uploaded the site so you can see it in action. Where it states "Title One", "Title Two", etc, this is what I want to bring  up towards the top of the div they're inside of.

example website url...    http://www.littleroomproductions.com/jQtest/

Below are the parts of code that I think need to be changed in order to bring the titles up to the top of the div...

//HTML

```
   <section class="box content">
    <div id="me"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Title One</h2>

      <p>This is where text goes </p>
            <div class="someContent">
                <p>click me</p>
            </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

//CSS used

```
section.box:last-child {
margin-bottom: 0;
}

section.box h2 {
padding-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 20px;
color: #606060;
font-family: serif;
font-size: 30px;
}

section.box p {
padding-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 20px;
color: black;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: cursive;
font-weight: 300;
}

section.box p:last-child {
margin-bottom: 300px;
}

section.box.content {
padding-top: 0;
padding-left: 40px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
 }

section.box.slide {
padding: 240px 0;
background-position: 0 0;
}

section.box.slide h1 {
color: yellow;
font-size: 48px;
/*line-height: 1;*/
font-weight: 700;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}
```

Comment: Your demo link is broken.

Comment: fixed the link to the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

`#me` `#projects` `#hire` have a 100px padding-top;

Comment: yes, that's for the nav bar at the top to jump to the content with the right amount of padding.  Changing those margins will not bring my titles up to the top of the white background div

Comment: There is no margin for that div, only padding-top. Removing that padding-top would bring your title up to the top.

Comment: oh I see now.  So I should add a margin-top to replace it so my nav bar jumps pad below the 60px from the fixed nav bar?

Comment: darn, margin-top just adds the same thing padding-top did.  I wish I could just tell the a href="#me" to jump to that id and then 100px down as well

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
section.box h2 {
padding-top: 0;
margin: -7px 0;
color: #606060;
font-family: serif;
font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: didn't quite bring it up, if I increase the margin the text below starts to overlap the title

Comment: sorry, i tried to answer without the right demo link.